# How to compare dates with moment

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to compare dates from database (firebase) with NOW. I'm using moment.js and it's not working. I think it has something to do with the time zone (or UTC+01:00)...

Example.

- date1: "2016-11-20T14:00:00"
- NOW: "2016-11-20T14:49:20+01:00"

I get NOW with `moment()` and compare like this:

```
var date1 = moment("2016-11-20T14:00:00");
moment(date1).isSameOrAfter( moment() ) // returns true
```

The comparison is precisely one hour off... How can I fix this? AND: is there any best practice in storing and comparing dates across time zones.

Comment: Please show the result of `moment("2016-11-20T16:00:00").format()`. I would guess the timezone of your pc is not `+01:00`.

Comment: "2016-11-20T14:00:00" will be parsed based on the host time zone offset. You should always pass the string format to the parser, otherwise it's just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates should always be saved in UTC. If you use string type the UTC date time value in ISO format.

So while saving convert from client time zone into UTC and while retrieving convert from UTC into client time zone.

Comparison should be done between two dates in the same time zone.

If the database value is in UTC and then you have to parse  as .utc() while creating a moment object.

```
moment.utc("2016-11-20T14:00:00");
```

Change the NOW value to UTC before comparing.

```
moment.(date1).utc()
```

Alternatively you can change the database value from UTC to local.

```
 moment.utc("2016-11-20T14:00:00").local()
```

Keep the NOW value as is before comparing.

Comment: It's working when converting date from firebase to local time:
moment.utc("2016-11-20T14:00:00").local().

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare the date you stored in Firebase with now() as it lacks the information about your timezone.

You can store dates using [`Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue)

For Example:

`date1: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

This will save your time in Unix Milliseconds (time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) by the Firebase Database servers.

Then you can compare with `new Date().getTime()` this will give your device time in Unix Milliseconds.

For Example:

```
if(new Date().getTime() >= date1) {
    //do something
}
```

Hope it helps :)